# Youtube api retrieve certain playlist items

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using youtube api to get videos from a playlist :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PL2MJN9x8D1E74fQH39DPaKP2b6SBMpeBi&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

what i want to know ! 
is there a way to use publishedAt filter to this api to get videos that where published after certain date ?

Answer (score 1):

The `publishedAt` getting returned from a Playlist query is the date the video was added to the playlist, rather than the date the video was published on YouTube.

For example, the first two items in the playlist say:

`"publishedAt": "2015-03-14T14:39:51.000Z"
"publishedAt": "2015-03-14T14:40:20.000Z"`

You may need to loop through the results and do another request (can use multiple URL-encoded, comma-separated ids to save requests) on each `videoId` to get the actual published dates

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=etAIpkdhU9Q%2CLo2qQmj0_h4&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

`"publishedAt": "2013-03-08T11:15:44.000Z"
"publishedAt": "2013-03-11T07:00:41.000Z"`