# Youtube Data API: Get latest video ID from channel excluding live streams

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

In my python script I'm getting the video ID of my latest video.

This is the code, `playlistId` being my channel's playlist ID that contains all my videos:

```py
def get_latest_video_id(youtube, playlistId): 
    id_request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part = 'snippet',
        playlistId = playlistId
    ) 
    id_response = id_request.execute()
    video_id = id_response['items'][0]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']
    return video_id
```

The problem now is, my live streams also get saved into this playlist. I couldn't find out if there is a playlist with all my uploads excluding my saved live streams.

The workaround I thought of is to get a list of all my livestreams and compare their ID to the ID I got from the method above.

My question is, isn't there a better way to do this? Is there by chance a API call that does what I need, without high quota cost?

Comment: If needing further help (and/or clarifications), just add comments under my answer below (SO will notify me automatically).

Comment: Please see the corrected `return` statement at the end of my answer. Sorry for that being wrong initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to iterate your call to [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint (using pagination) for to filter out manually the videos that are live streams.

```py
def get_non_livestream_videos(youtube, video_ids):
    assert len(video_ids) <= 50
    if not video_ids: return []

    response = youtube.videos().list(
        fields = 'items(id,liveStreamingDetails)',
        part = 'id,liveStreamingDetails',
        maxResults = len(video_ids),
        id = ','.join(video_ids),
    ).execute()

    items = response.get('items', [])
    assert len(items) <= len(video_ids)

    not_live = lambda video: \
        not video.get('liveStreamingDetails')
    video_id = lambda video: video['id']

    return map(video_id, filter(not_live, items))

def get_latest_video_id(youtube, playlistId): 
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        fields = 'nextPageToken,items/snippet/resourceId',
        playlistId = playlistId,
        maxResults = 50,
        part = 'snippet'
    )

    is_video = lambda item: \
        item['snippet']['resourceId']['kind'] == 'youtube#video'
    video_id = lambda item: \
        item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']

    while request:
        response = request.execute()

        items = response.get('items', [])
        assert len(items) <= 50

        videos = map(video_id, filter(is_video, items))
        if videos:
            videos = get_non_livestream_videos(youtube, videos)
            if videos: return videos[0]

        request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
            request, response)

    return None
```

Note that above I used the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter for to get from the APIs only the info that's actually needed.

Also note that you may have to elaborate a bit the function `get_non_livestream_videos`, since the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint queried with its [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) parameter as a comma-separated list of video IDs *may well alter the order* of the items it returns w.r.t. the given order of the IDs in `video_ids`.

Yet an important note: if you're running the code above under Python 3 (your question does not mention this), then make sure you have the following *configuration* code inserted at the top of your script:

```
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    from builtins import map as builtin_map
    map = lambda *args: list(builtin_map(*args))
```

This is needed since, under Python 3, the builtin function [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an *iterator*, whereas under Python 2, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) returns a *list*.

---

Here is the code that solves the issue I mentioned above w.r.t. the case of `Videos.list` altering the order of items returned relative to the order of the IDs given by the argument `video_ids` of function `get_non_livestream_videos`:

```py
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    from builtins import map as builtin_map
    map = lambda *args: list(builtin_map(*args))

class MergeVideoListsError(Exception): pass

def merge_video_lists(video_ids, video_res):
    pair0 = lambda pair: pair[0]
    pair1 = lambda pair: pair[1]

    video_ids = sorted(
        enumerate(video_ids), key = pair1)
    video_res.sort(
        key = lambda video: video['id'])

    def error(video_id):
        raise MergeVideoListsError(
            "unexpected video resource of ID '%s'" % video_id)

    def do_merge():
        N = len(video_ids)
        R = len(video_res)
        assert R <= N

        l = []
        i, j = 0, 0
        while i < N and j < R:
            v = video_ids[i]
            r = video_res[j]
            s = v[1]
            d = r['id']
            if s == d:
                l.append((v[0], r))
                i += 1
                j += 1
            elif s < d:
                i += 1
            else:
                error(d)

        if j < R:
            error(video_res[j]['id'])

        return l

    video_res = do_merge()
    video_res.sort(key = pair0)
    return map(pair1, video_res)

def println(*args):
    for a in args:
        sys.stdout.write(str(a))
    sys.stdout.write('\n')

def test_merge_video_lists(ids, res, val):
    try:
        println("ids:   ", ids)
        println("res:   ", res)
        r = merge_video_lists(ids, res)
        println("merge: ", r)
    except MergeVideoListsError as e:
        println("error: ", e)
        r = str(e)
    finally:
        println("test:  ", "OK" \
            if val == r \
            else "failed")

TESTS = ((
    ['c', 'b', 'a'],
    [{'id': 'c'}, {'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}],
    [{'id': 'c'}, {'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'a'}]
),(
    ['c', 'b', 'a'],
    [{'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'c'}],
    [{'id': 'c'}, {'id': 'b'}]
),(
    ['c', 'b', 'a'],
    [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'c'}],
    [{'id': 'c'}, {'id': 'a'}]
),(
    ['c', 'b', 'a'],
    [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}],
    [{'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'a'}]
),(
    ['c', 'b', 'a'],
    [{'id': 'z'}, {'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'c'}],
    "unexpected video resource of ID 'z'"
),(
    ['c', 'b', 'a'],
    [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'z'}, {'id': 'c'}],
    "unexpected video resource of ID 'z'"
),(
    ['c', 'b', 'a'],
    [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'z'}],
    "unexpected video resource of ID 'z'"
))

def main():
    for i, t in enumerate(TESTS):
        if i: println()
        test_merge_video_lists(*t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# $ python merge-video-lists.py
# ids:   ['c', 'b', 'a']
# res:   [{'id': 'c'}, {'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}]
# merge: [{'id': 'c'}, {'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'a'}]
# test:  OK
# 
# ids:   ['c', 'b', 'a']
# res:   [{'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'c'}]
# merge: [{'id': 'c'}, {'id': 'b'}]
# test:  OK
# 
# ids:   ['c', 'b', 'a']
# res:   [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'c'}]
# merge: [{'id': 'c'}, {'id': 'a'}]
# test:  OK
# 
# ids:   ['c', 'b', 'a']
# res:   [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}]
# merge: [{'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'a'}]
# test:  OK
# 
# ids:   ['c', 'b', 'a']
# res:   [{'id': 'z'}, {'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'c'}]
# error: unexpected video resource of ID 'z'
# test:  OK
# 
# ids:   ['c', 'b', 'a']
# res:   [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'z'}, {'id': 'c'}]
# error: unexpected video resource of ID 'z'
# test:  OK
# 
# ids:   ['c', 'b', 'a']
# res:   [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}, {'id': 'z'}]
# error: unexpected video resource of ID 'z'
# test:  OK
```

The code above is a standalone program (running both under Python v2 and v3) that implements a *merging* function `merge_video_lists`.

You'll have to use this function within the function `get_non_livestream_videos` by replacing the line:

```
return map(video_id, filter(not_live, items))
```

with:

```
return map(video_id, merge_video_lists(
    video_ids, filter(not_live, items)))
```

for Python 2. For Python 3 the replacement would be:

```
return map(video_id, merge_video_lists(
    video_ids, list(filter(not_live, items))))
```

Instead of replacing the `return` statement, just have that statement preceded by this one:

```
items = merge_video_lists(video_ids, items)
```

This latter variant is better, since it also validates the video IDs returned by the API: if there is an ID that is not in `video_ids`, then `merge_video_lists` throws a `MergeVideoListsError` exception indicating the culprit ID.

---

For obtaining all videos that are exactly `N` days old, excluding live streams, use the function below:

```py
def get_days_old_video_ids(youtube, playlistId, days = 7): 
    from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
    n_days = date.today() - timedelta(days = days)

    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        fields = 'nextPageToken,items(snippet/resourceId,contentDetails/videoPublishedAt)',
        part = 'snippet,contentDetails',
        playlistId = playlistId,
        maxResults = 50
    )

    def parse_published_at(item):
        details = item['contentDetails']
        details['videoPublishedAt'] = datetime.strptime(
            details['videoPublishedAt'],
            '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') \
            .date()
        return item

    def find_if(cond, items):
        for item in items:
            if cond(item):
                return True
        return False

    n_days_eq = lambda item: \
        item['contentDetails']['videoPublishedAt'] == n_days
    n_days_lt = lambda item: \
        item['contentDetails']['videoPublishedAt'] < n_days
    is_video = lambda item: \
        item['snippet']['resourceId']['kind'] == 'youtube#video'
    video_id = lambda item: \
        item['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']

    videos = []

    while request:
        response = request.execute()

        items = response.get('items', [])
        assert len(items) <= 50

        # remove the non-video entries in 'items'
        items = filter(is_video, items)

        # replace each 'videoPublishedAt' with
        # its corresponding parsed date object
        items = map(parse_published_at, items)

        # terminate loop when found a 'videoPublishedAt' < n_days
        done = find_if(n_days_lt, items)

        # retain only the items with 'videoPublishedAt' == n_days
        items = filter(n_days_eq, items)

        # add to 'videos' the IDs of videos in 'items' that are not live streams
        videos.extend(get_non_livestream_videos(youtube, map(video_id, items)))

        if done: break

        request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
            request, response)

    return videos
```

The function `get_days_old_video_ids` above needs `filter` and `map` to return lists, therefore the *configuration* code above has to be updated to:

```py
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    from builtins import map as builtin_map
    map = lambda *args: list(builtin_map(*args))
    from builtins import filter as builtin_filter
    filter = lambda *args: list(builtin_filter(*args))
```

Do note that `get_days_old_video_ids` is relying on the following [*undocumented property*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004531/8327971) of the result set produced by `PlaylistItems.list`: *for the uploads playlist of a channel, the items returned by `PlaylistItems.list` are ordered in reverse chronological order (newest first) by `contentDetails.videoPublishedAt`.*

Therefore you have to make sure the argument `playlistId` of `get_days_old_video_ids` is the ID of the uploads playlist of your channel. Usually, a channel ID and its corresponding uploads playlist ID are related by `s/^UC([0-9a-zA-Z_-]{22})$/UU\1/`.

Also note that `get_days_old_video_ids` is returning the IDs of videos that are *exactly* `days` old. If needing to obtain the IDs of videos that are *at most* `days` old, then have defined:

```
    n_days_ge = lambda item: \
        item['contentDetails']['videoPublishedAt'] >= n_days
```

and have `n_days_eq` replaced with `n_days_ge`.

Yet something to note: at the top of function `get_non_livestream_videos` above, I added the statement:

```
    if not video_ids: return []
```

such that to avoid processing an empty `video_ids` list.

Comment: Thank you! Since I'm not really a programmer, just trying to automate some things in my life, this answer is extremely helpful.

Comment: Sorry for asking this, I need to modfiy your solution to only get videos that are exactly 7 days old (again, excluding live streams). Is it possible to just modify your code for this, or is a completely different code needed?

Comment: @user3566608: Did you succeeded integrating `get_days_old_video_ids` in your app?