# YouTube Data API: Exclude livestreams from Search.list result set

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

Today I have an (I think) simple question.
I want to exclude YouTube live streams from my YouTube Data API `Search.list` result sets.
How can I do that? I can't find a function to do that in the docs from the API.

That's what I tried:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=UCZMsvbAhhRblVGXmEXW8TSA&part=snippet,id&order=viewCount&maxResults=1&regionCode=DE&eventType=completed&type=video&publishedAfter=2021-02-05T00:00:00Z&key={KEY}`

But that includes live streams, I want to remove them from the search. The live streams has always `LIVE` in the video title, maybe that helps. I tried also to use `q`, but I get always 0 search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is the following: you'll have to filter out manually the videos that are live streams from each result set obtained from the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint.

The longer answer follows below:

A given video is a live stream if and only if that video has attached the property [`liveStreamingDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails).

I'd warmly recommend to go through a very recent [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743649/8327971) that details a Python solution to precisely this issue, the function `get_non_livestream_videos`:

```py
def get_non_livestream_videos(youtube, video_ids):
    assert len(video_ids) <= 50
    if not video_ids: return []

    response = youtube.videos().list(
        fields = 'items(id,liveStreamingDetails)',
        part = 'id,liveStreamingDetails',
        maxResults = len(video_ids),
        id = ','.join(video_ids),
    ).execute()

    items = response.get('items', [])
    assert len(items) <= len(video_ids)

    not_live = lambda video: \
        not video.get('liveStreamingDetails')
    video_id = lambda video: video['id']

    return map(video_id, filter(not_live, items))
```

If you have a list of video IDs `video_ids` then this function calls the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint for to determine the existence of the property `liveStreamingDetails` for each of the respective videos. Any video that has such a property gets filtered out from the resulting list of video IDs.

Note that above I used the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter for to get from the APIs only the info that's actually needed.

Also note that a precondition of using `get_non_livestream_videos` is that its list argument `video_ids` to be of at most 50 elements.

This is not an actual restriction when using this function, because it's supposed to be used on a list of video IDs that's obtained from a paged API result set. (`Search.list` returns paginated result sets of at most 50 items.)

---

The solution indicated above excludes from a list of video IDs all the videos that are *upcoming*, *live*, or *completed live* broadcasts.

Notice that videos corresponding to *completed live broadcasts* are excluded too.

Now, if you don't want these kind of videos to be excluded from your result set (that is that you need to have excluded the videos corresponding to only upcoming or currently live broadcasts), then there's a simpler solution to your inquiry:

The [`Search resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource) objects returned by the `Search.list` endpoint provide the following property:

> [**`snippet.liveBroadcastContent`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#snippet.liveBroadcastContent) (string)
>
> An indication of whether a `video` or `channel` resource has live broadcast content. Valid property values are `upcoming`, `live`, and `none`.
>
> For a `video` resource, a value of `upcoming` indicates that the video is a live broadcast that has not yet started, while a value of `live` indicates that the video is an active live broadcast. For a `channel` resource, a value of `upcoming` indicates that the channel has a scheduled broadcast that has not yet started, while a value of `live` indicates that the channel has an active live broadcast.

Consequently, you may well filter out manually from `Search.list` queries the videos having `snippet.liveBroadcastContent` of value different than `none` as simply as shown below:

```py
not_live = lambda item: \
    item['snippet']['liveBroadcastContent'] == 'none'

request = youtube.search().list(
    fields = 'nextPageToken,items(id,snippet)',
    publishedAfter = '2021-02-05T00:00:00Z',
    channelId = 'UCZMsvbAhhRblVGXmEXW8TSA',
    part = 'id,snippet',
    order = 'viewCount',
    regionCode = 'DE',
    maxResults = 50,
    type = 'video'
)
videos = []

while request:
    response = request.execute()
    items = response.get('items', [])
    videos.extend(filter(not_live, items))
    request = youtube.search().list_next(
        request, response)
```

An important note: the solution above is simple, but limited by the following specification of the `channelId` request parameter of `Search.list`:

> [**`channelId`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) (string)
>
> The `channelId` parameter indicates that the API response should only contain resources created by the channel.
>
> **Note:** Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the `channelId` parameter and sets the [`type`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) parameter value to `video`, but it does not also set one of the [`forContentOwner`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forContentOwner), [`forDeveloper`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forDeveloper), or [`forMine`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#forMine) filters.

Consequently, the pagination loop above, over the result sets provided by `Search.list`, would lead to a `videos` list of at most 500 elements.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and couldn't find a parameter to filter out the live broadcasting.

I did the way with just the `duration` property in the response. Seems like the broadcasting duration has a const value `P0D` instead of an actual duration. I use that to filter out the videos I don't want.