# Getting info if video is live through PlaylistItems feed, instead of sending another query for the video. Youtube API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As the title says, I would like to see if there is a way to save some quotas on this, when fetching uploads playlist the live video is in it, but there is no info about whether it is live or not.

I can get that info if I send another query with the video ID but seems like a waste of already limited quotas.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: The answer to your question is, unfortunately, negative.

Comment: See this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65743649/8327971) for how to do that minimizing quota consumption.