# Can I get YouTube video tag using Google Application Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I want to send an email once new YouTube video was published. I need to somehow select what video will trigger the email. I thought I would use tags. But how can I access the tags?

I am using this [sample script](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/apps-script) to list all my videos. It works well but I do not know how to access the tags. From the searches I have done here on SO and Google it seems to me that is not possible using Google Application Script but the documentation [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) says `... For example, in a playlist resource, the snippet property contains properties like author, title, description, **TAGS**, and timeCreated. As such, if you set part=snippet, the API response will contain all of those properties...`

So it looks like that I might be able to get tags of videos. Could someone help me how?

What I want is the tag `my_tag` as the picture shows
[image]

```
function retrieveMyUploads() {
  var results = YouTube.Channels.list('contentDetails', {mine: true});
  for(var i in results.items) {
    var item = results.items[i];
    // Get the playlist ID, which is nested in contentDetails, as described in the
    // Channel resource: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels
    var playlistId = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;

    var nextPageToken = '';

    // This loop retrieves a set of playlist items and checks the nextPageToken in the
    // response to determine whether the list contains additional items. It repeats that process
    // until it has retrieved all of the items in the list.
    while (nextPageToken != null) {
      var playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        maxResults: 25,
        pageToken: nextPageToken
      });

      for (var j = 0; j < playlistResponse.items.length; j++) {
        var playlistItem = playlistResponse.items[j];
        Logger.log('[%s] Title: %s',
                   playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId,
                   playlistItem.snippet.title);

      }
      nextPageToken = playlistResponse.nextPageToken;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about the relationship between your current script and your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: The script list all my videos, in particular video ID and title. I want to get also that tags.

Comment: I updated my question and added the picture of what I want.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the official document of "PlaylistItems", I cannot find "tags". [Ref](https://developers.google.cn/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) So in this case, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use the method of "Videos: list" for retrieving the tags.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for (var j = 0; j < playlistResponse.items.length; j++) {
  var playlistItem = playlistResponse.items[j];
  Logger.log('[%s] Title: %s',
             playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId,
             playlistItem.snippet.title);

}
```

To:

```
for (var j = 0; j < playlistResponse.items.length; j++) {
  var playlistItem = playlistResponse.items[j];
  Logger.log('[%s] Title: %s',
             playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId,
             playlistItem.snippet.title);
  
  // I added below script.
  var res = YouTube.Videos.list('snippet', {id: playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId});
  var tagList = res.items.map(e => ({id: e.id, tags: e.snippet.tags}));
  Logger.log(tagList)
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple modification. So please modify it to your actual situation.
- If you don't want to use `YouTube.Videos.list` in a loop, I think that you can also use the following script using the batch request. When you use this script, please install the GAS library for batch request. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install)

  ```
    function myFcuntion() {
      var results = YouTube.Channels.list('contentDetails', {mine: true});
      for(var i in results.items) {
        var item = results.items[i];
        // Get the playlist ID, which is nested in contentDetails, as described in the
        // Channel resource: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels
        var playlistId = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;

        var nextPageToken = '';

        // This loop retrieves a set of playlist items and checks the nextPageToken in the
        // response to determine whether the list contains additional items. It repeats that process
        // until it has retrieved all of the items in the list.

        var videoIds = [];  // Added
        while (nextPageToken != null) {
          var playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {
            playlistId: playlistId,
            maxResults: 25,
            pageToken: nextPageToken,
            fields: "items"
          });

          for (var j = 0; j < playlistResponse.items.length; j++) {
            var playlistItem = playlistResponse.items[j];
            Logger.log('[%s] Title: %s',
                      playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId,
                      playlistItem.snippet.title);

            videoIds.push(playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId);  // Added
          }
          nextPageToken = playlistResponse.nextPageToken;
        }

        // I added below script.
        var requests = {
          batchPath: "batch/youtube/v3",
          requests: videoIds.map(id => ({
            method: "GET",
            endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=${id}`,
          })),
          accessToken: ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
        };
        var result = BatchRequest.EDo(requests); // Using GAS library
        var tagList = result.flatMap(({items}, i) => items.map(({snippet}) => ({id: videoIds[i], tags: snippet.tags})));
        Logger.log(tagList);
      }
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.cn/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems)
- [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.cn/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)
- [Videos: list](https://developers.google.cn/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I do not understand why this url got "tags" https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list but this one does not https://developers.google.cn/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Comment: would you know if `YouTube.PlaylistItems.list` result is sorted by publishedAt? And how to find out?

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, unfortunately, I couldn't find the parameter of the API for sorting the result values. I apologize for this. By this, in the current stage, when you want to sort the result values, it is required to sort the values using a script after the values were retrieved. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Radek: indeed the `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint returns a result set sorted by `videoPublishedAt` when *queried with its `playlistId` parameter set to the ID of the uploads playlist of a channel*. This property of the endpoint *is not documented* as such, but have a look at [my argument in favor of its existence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004531/8327971).

Comment: @stvar Thank you for your additional information. And, I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike: you really don't have to apologize; nobody would consider a (quote) *Ph.D. in Physics / Google Developer Expert (GDE)* to be an unskilled person.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for replying. When I could obtain new information, I always have both thanks and apology. If my English for my replying is not correct, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike: I understand what you're saying. Honesty acknowledging one's own limited knowledge is to (should) be appreciated by everyone. Yet (in my opinion) a simple thanks suffices.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for replying. I would like to refer to your advice.

Comment: @Tanaike: on the other hand, as far as I know, using the endpoint `batch/youtube/v3` does not reduce the quota consumption when used for repeated calling the very same API endpoint (in your case: the `Videos.list` endpoint). The [`batch/youtube/v3` endpoint's purpose](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/batch.md) is nothing more than: *allow your application to put several API calls into a single HTTP request.*

Comment: @Tanaike: For to actually reduce the quota cost of invoking `Videos.list` several times in a row, do use it's `id` parameter *set to a comma-separated list of max 50 video IDs.* Irrespective of the number of video IDs received (as long as that number does not exceed 50), that endpoint's [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) is 1 unit per call.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for replying. I understand your replying. Yes. I have known that the multiple IDs can be used for `YouTube.Videos.list`. But `YouTube.Videos.list` is the GET method. So I'm worry that when the query parameter is large by increasing IDs, an error might occur. So I proposed above direction. For example, can I think that 50 IDs can be surely used for `YouTube.Videos.list`?

Comment: @Tanaike: that max of 50 is not documented as such; but is derived from the (all most general) property of the results sets of this API: with only a few exceptions (`CommentThreads.list` and `Comments.list`), all endpoints that return paginated result sets have their pages of max 50 items. I also can state doing actual experiments that  confirmed this property to be true in case of `Videos.list`.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for the information. From your replying, I could know new information that 50 IDs can be used for `YouTube.Videos.list`. And also, now I confirmed it using the script. When 51 IDs are used, an error like `The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.` occurs. I think that by using this and batch request, the process cost might be able to be reduced more.

Comment: @Tanaike: you're right worrying that the actual URL composed upon adding many video IDs to the `id` request parameter of `Videos.list` endpoint could well be long enough to cause trouble. The API's is not documenting the maximum length of the URL it is accepting; but public open-sourced code of Google [indicate that maximum length to be 2K](https://github.com/dossett/google-api-python-client/blob/6f82438ad029888444133634bf6bdedb64f9faa9/googleapiclient/http.py#L891).

Comment: @Tanaike: if an composed URL exceeds 2K, then do exactly the the source code quoted above does: convert the `GET` method to a `POST` method seasoned with a HTTP header of form: `x-http-method-override: GET`. But in case of `Videos.list`, since video IDs are of length 11 (not documented officially, but true from long time experince with them), that endpoint's URL would not exceed the 2K length limit.

Comment: @stvar It seems that 1 ID is 11 bytes. When 50 IDs are used, the length of endpoint is 660 bytes with no error. When 51 IDs are used, it's 672 bytes. But an error occurs at 51 IDs. So I thought that the limitation might be set in the internal server side.

Comment: @Tanaike: Indeed, I also think that the 2K limits is set to be checked within the server prior to any internal API call be issued; the 50 limit is an API limit to be checked by the API back-end itself after the 2K limit got verified by the server's generic HTTP request handler.

Comment: @stvar About `I also think that the 2K limits is set to be checked within the server prior to any internal API call be issued`, in this case, when I had tested about this using the method of files.list in Drive API, I surely confirmed this. So the maximum number of IDs given by Google side might be realistic.