# Reduce quota from YouTube API when calling channel videos?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been using the YouTube Data API and I want to just call the API and for it to return a channel's latest video. Currently I have been doing this:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=[key]&channelId=[channelId]&part=id&order=date&maxResults=1`,

but that still uses many units.

Is there any way to get the data I need without using so many units?

Comment: Have you considered applying for a quota extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question of yours:

> I want to just call the API and for it to return a channel's latest video.

the answer is positive. You'll have to proceed as follows:

***Step 1:** Obtain the ID of the uploads playlist corresponding to the channel of your interest:*

For a given channel -- identified by its ID `CHANNEL_ID` --, invoke the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint, queried with its request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id) set to `CHANNEL_ID`:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&fields=items/contentDetails/relatedPlaylists/uploads&id=CHANNEL_ID&key=...`.

The needed uploads playlist ID is to be found as the value of the property [`contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads) of the [Channels resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource) JSON object returned by the endpoint.

Usually, a channel ID and its corresponding uploads playlist ID are related by `s/^UC([0-9a-zA-Z_-]{22})$/UU\1/`.

Note that above I used the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) request parameter for to get from the API only the info that's actually needed.

Also note that you'll have to invoke `Channels.list` as above only once, for to use the obtained uploads playlist ID as many times as you need.

***Step 2:** Obtain the latest uploaded video of the channel of your interest:*

For that you'll need to rely on an undocumented behavior of the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoint queried with its [`playlistId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) request parameter set to the ID you've obtained at step 1:

According to point 2 of [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65004531/8327971):

> For the uploads playlist of a channel, the items returned by `PlaylistItems.list` API endpoint are (*have to be*) ordered in reverse chronological order by `contentDetails.videoPublishedAt`.

Therefore, you'll have to invoke `PlaylistItems.list` on the following URL repeatedly in a loop (using [pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination)):

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=UPLOADS_ID&part=snippet&fields=nextPageToken,items/snippet/resourceId&maxResults=50&pageToken=PAGE_TOKEN&key=...`

Above, `UPLOADS_ID` is the ID of the uploads playlist obtained at step 1.

The request parameter `pageToken=PAGE_TOKEN` is needed if and only if you're not invoking `PlaylistItems.list` for the first time. When the endpoint is invoked the `N`-th time, with `N >= 2`, then `PAGE_TOKEN` would be the value of the property `nextPageToken` of the JSON response obtained from the previous endpoint call. If an endpoint call does not provide the property `nextPageToken` then the pagination loop terminates.

The pagination of the result sets of `PlaylistItems.list` is needed for the sake of correctness of you implementation: you'll have to ignore the `snippet` objects of the `items` array obtained from each endpoint call when the value of the property [`snippet.resourceId.kind`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#snippet.resourceId.kind) is not equal with `youtube#video`.

For each `snippet` object obtained from the endpoint that has `snippet.resourceId.kind` equal to `youtube#video`, the property [`snippet.resourceId.videoId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#snippet.resourceId.videoId) is set to the ID of an uploaded video belonging to the playlist identified by `UPLOADS_ID`.

Therefore, the first time you encounter a `snippet` object of this latter kind, you retain the respective video ID and break off the pagination loop (thus invoking `PlaylistItems.list` no more).

---

For what concerns your second question:

> Is there any way to get the data I need without using so many units?

again, the answer is positive.

Taking into account the [quota costs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost), executing *the step 1 taken once and the step 2 taken N times* amounts to a cost of `1 + N * 1 = N + 1` units. Moreover, if step 1 is not executed, then the cost would be `N` units. (You need not execute step 1 once you already know `UPLOADS_ID` from previous runs of step 1 + 2.)

Also note that *your pagination loop will most likely terminate with `N` being 1*; thus your API calls would entail most probably only 2 units of quota cost. When step 1 is not executed, the quota cost implied would most probably be only 1 unit.

Answer (score 0):

the following cost 2 unit

```
baseurl = https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3
```

Get channel `"Upload"` ID

```
{baseurl}/channels?part=contentDetails&id={channel Id}&key={api key}
```

then use upload id for `playlistItems`

```
{baseurl}/v3/playlistItems?playlistId={upload id}&part=snippet&maxResults={max numbers}&key={api key}
```